# Verbal agreement of "more of + plural noun"

Tags: verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns, determiners

[Here Are More Of The Most Amazing Images Of Cars](https://jalopnik.com/here-are-more-of-the-most-amazing-images-of-exploding-c-1774361071)

Is the sentence grammatical?

Shouldn't it concoord ***is*** with the uncountable ***more (of)***, instead of its current plural ***are***?

According to Microsoft® Encarta® 2009:

4. additional: indicates something additional or further (pronoun + singular or plural verb)

adjective: *I need more light.*

pronoun: *There **aren't** any more of these*.

pronoun: *No more is expected*.

Comment: Find the noun. Verb 'are' agrees with plural subject 'amazing images'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Reordering the sentence, then , _More Of The Most Amazing Images Of Cars are here_? is this grammatically OK?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: "More" is a fused determiner-head NP in a partitive construction. The NP "more of the most amazing images of cars" is partitive in the sense that it denotes a subset of the set consisting of the most amazing images of cars". Since the subset is plural, so must the verb be.

Answer (score 1):

**more** can be understood as multiple in such partitive constructions with a plural countable noun:

> We questioned 100 people. **More of them** *like* sunshine than sleet.

and as singular with a singular uncountable noun:

> The company spends a lot of money.  **More of it** *goes* to energy than to taxes.

Comment: But proxinity agreement is found with 'more than one of them': 'More than one of them was killed.'